How to Ensure a Sticky Table Header (<thead>) Remains on Top of Relatively Positioned Table Cells?
It works if I use z-index: 1; on the th (commented out in the snippet), but I cannot use this strategy to fix this because it interferes with other elements.
Also, I need to have the content of a cell as position: relative, too.
Is there any other strategy to solve this?
Here you have a complete example:


table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /*z-index: 1; /* Ensures the header is above other positioned elements */
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
      <td>
        <div style="background-color:red" class="relative">
          THIS CELL OVERLAPS THE HEADER
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Row 1, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Repeat rows to ensure enough content for scrolling -->
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Why dont you add ex z-index:-9 to your .relative class it will be below the header

This is bad practice to put in random numbers, please when you provide an answer make sure you put in numbers that are relevant. -9 is not necessary, and multiple layering with such radical numbers could lead to problems later on, it's better to put in meaningful numbers, like 0 for the bottom layer, 1 for the middle, so on.

You most likely need to modify your z-indexes for the different elements.
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2; /* Make header go above the .relative element */
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; /* Go below thead element */
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

